# C# Listview stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, listview, stored-procedures

I got this problem with a `ListView` + database.

My question is: why is my ListView showing 2 username columns and 1 email, instead of username, code, email (I have made username, code and email columns in the `ListView` on the form)..

You can see the stored procedure I wrote and the C# code below..

PS. I use Visual Studio 2012.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong :/

Hope there is a easy way to do it :)

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ShowFamily
as
    SELECT 
       username, code, email
    FROM 
       Family
    ORDER BY 
       username
```

When I make it run by my c# code it's show 2 times username and email. Not "Code"

My C# code:

```
 public void GetData()
 {
        datareader = null;

        sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "SP_ShowFamily";

        try
        {
            sqlConnenction.Open();
            datareader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            ListViewItem itmx;

            while (datareader.Read())
            {
                itmx = new ListViewItem();
                itmx.Text = datareader.GetValue(0).ToString();

                for (int i = 0; i < datareader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    itmx.SubItems.Add(datareader.GetValue(i).ToString());
                }

                listView1.Items.Add(itmx);
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (datareader != null)
            {
                datareader.Close();
            }

            if (sqlConnenction.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlConnenction.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

You are displaying `username` once (in the first ListView column) here:

```
itmx.Text = datareader.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

and then again when `i` is `0` in the first SubItem (second ListView column):

```
itmx.SubItems.Add(datareader.GetValue(i).ToString());
```

Try changing your `for` loop to start at `i = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

First get the DataReader columns and assign them to the ListView:

```
for(int i=0;i<datareader.FieldCount;i++)
{
   ListView1.Columns.Add(datareader.GetName(i));
}
```

Then insert data records in the ListView:

```
string[] arr = new string[datareader.FieldCount];
ListViewItem itmx;
while (datareader.Read())
{
    for(int i=0;i<datareader.FieldCount;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=datareader.GetValue(i).ToString();
    }
    itmx = new ListViewItem();
    listView1.Items.Add(itmx);
}
```

Caution: The code is untested and should be considered as pseudo-code only.